# Jekyll search with jekyll-lunr-js-search not loading full body in search.json

Tags: ruby, json, full-text-search, jekyll

I'm trying to implement search functionality in a Jekyll-generated static website via jekyll-lunr-js-search (see [here](https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search)). 
The search functionality works if the searched string appears outside of a html or highlight tag, or in the title, plain body text... 
But if I look for a word or part of a word that appears inside a tag in the post (.md file), it's not found.

Inspecting the search.json entry for that particular post, I see indeed that the body does not contain this content...
Is this a known issue? Or is this a configuration problem?

The post would e.g. contain 
    `<ul><li>Labyrinth</li></ul> Bicycle races are fun yes yes!`

and the body content in search.json would then be : `body: "Bicycle races are fun yes yes!"`
Searching for 'Lab' would return no results then.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem with the plugin. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/slashdotdash/jekyll-lunr-js-search/blob/master/build/jekyll_lunr_js_search.rb#L106), we can see that it builds the search index by scanning the text from the rendered page.

```
def render(item)
  item.render({}, @site.site_payload)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(item.output)
  paragraphs = doc.search('//text()').map {|t| t.content }
  paragraphs = paragraphs.join(" ").gsub("\r", " ").gsub("\n", " ").gsub("\t", " ").gsub(/\s+/, " ")
end
```

You could modify the plugin and change the `//text()` XPath to be a CSS selector you need, since [Nokogiri's search](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-search) allows for both XPath and CSS searching.